# How to print out number of checkboxes base on a particular number in php

Tags: php

How can I print out number of checkboxes base on a particular number.

let say if my variable is 12 or 4 for instance, I want my checkboxes to appear twelve times or four times.

Comment: Use a [for loop](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) to echo your checkbox HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $your_var; $i++) {
    echo "<input type='checkbox'>";
}
```

?

Comment: please I'm new to programming. how can i print out the numbers with each checkbox. Here is what I did  <?php
              $s = 12;
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $s; $i++) {
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' value='$i'> '.$i.'";
                }

                ?> but the numbers are not printing out.

Comment: You can use label - echo "< input type='checkbox' value='$i' id='checkbox_".$i."'> < label for='checkbox_".$i."'> $i< /label> ";

Answer (score -1):

A simple one liner would be to create an array with 12 checkbox was and implode them with new lines.

```
echo implode("<br>\n", array_fill(0,12,"<input type='checkbox'>"));
```

Array_fill first argument is the start key, the second is the end key.
`0,12` means 12 items of the third argument which is the checkbox html.
Then send that to implode which adds the glue between the strings, which I choosed to be new line, but you can change that to what you want.

Output:

```
<input type='checkbox'><br>
<input type='checkbox'><br>
<input type='checkbox'><br>
<input type='checkbox'><br>
<input type='checkbox'><br>
<input type='checkbox'><br>
<input type='checkbox'><br>
<input type='checkbox'><br>
<input type='checkbox'><br>
<input type='checkbox'><br>
<input type='checkbox'><br>
<input type='checkbox'>
```

https://3v4l.org/gLINO